# Forced region split in HBase not causing any splits

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hbase, amazon-emr, apache-phoenix

I have an EMR cluster running HBase on s3. I have a table with the following configuration

> hbase.regionserver.region.split.policy = org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.DisabledRegionSplitPolicy

I have disabled the split policy because I want to run split commands manually.
So I have a region say 'e85b1fe7c708500a7ae44427a76b3391' whose size is 14GB. I issue the following split command on the region:

> split 'e85b1fe7c708500a7ae44427a76b3391'

The command runs successfully on the hbase shell, but no region split occurs. Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Even though a force-split (such as the 'split' command in hbase shell) should be expected to expected to ignore 'DisabledRegionSplitPolicy', and try splitting a region, I have found, at least in the versions 1.4.x, that the policy is stopping the force-split.
You may try changing to some other policy, say 'ConstantSizeRegionSplitPolicy'. If this doesn't fix, then the issue could be something else. In that case, enable debug level in logging both in master, and in the target region server (which is hosting the target region), and troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

Based on information available in https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#manual_region_splitting_decisions it states `The DisabledRegionSplitPolicy policy blocks manual region splitting.`.

If you want to avoid manual splits, you can increase the size for auto-split to something very large.